# Recursive function ending early in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, recursion

### Problem

I have a recursive function which loops through about 20,000 items in an array.
 It works fine on desktop, but stops after about 10,600 iterations in iOS Safari and Chrome.

### Attempts

*Note: I'm doing this in a web worker to avoid blocking the UI, but the issue can be reproduced without one, so I removed it for testing. I also removed the array and I'm just incrementing `i` in the following code.*

**First attempt** *(does not finish on iOS)***:**

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var i = 0, max = 20000, status = document.body;
    foo();

    function foo(){
 status.innerHTML = i + '/' + max; // Just for testing - not in my code
 if(i < max){
     i++;
     foo();  // Calling the function immediately
        }
    }
};
```

**Second attempt** *(works, but is really slow)***:**

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var i = 0, max = 20000, status = document.body;
    foo();

    function foo(){
 status.innerHTML = i + '/' + max; // Just for testing - not in my code
 if(i < max){
     i++;
     setTimeout(foo,0);  // Using a timeout
        }
    }
};
```

**Third attempt** *(works great, but looks hacky)***:**

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var i = 0, max = 20000, status = document.body;
    foo();

    function foo(){
 status.innerHTML = i + '/' + max; // Just for testing - not in my code
 if(i < max){
     i++;
     if(i%1000 == 0) setTimeout(foo,0);  // Using timeout every 1000 items
     else foo();                         // Calling immediately otherwise
        }
    }
};
```

### Questions

1. Why is the first attempt not working? Is it because of memory?
2. Although the third attempt works fine, it seems to be hacky, so I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: I reckon it's either a memory issue OR you're hitting the stack limit. I guess this would be down to the hardware of the machine/device as to what this limit is. Can you debug/get more info on the JS error.

Comment: A quick search around and I've seen a few mentions of avoiding recursion on iOS if possible. I know we're seeing a stripped down version of the code here but is there any way you can convert the code to work iteratively with a while loop for instance?

Comment: @scgough Thank you for your comments. Unfortunately, I don't know of an easy way to debug the code on my iPhone using Windows (found [this](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy), but I can't make it work). I absolutely can use a `while` or a `for` loop, I just used recursion here in order to use a timeout because it did not work with a `for` loop. I'll try with a `while`, but the results might be the same.

Comment: Why not just use a `for` or `while` loop and avoid recursion and stack issues?

Comment: @scgough Thank you! I must have screwed up the first time, it actually works with `for` and `while`... So what you two are basically saying is that there is a stack overflow when calling the function recursively because it keeps every iteration in memory until it ends (not the case in a regular loop)?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. If you can use an iterative loop rather than recursion then always go that route I say! Glad to be of service @blex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the first attempt not working? Is it because of memory?

Your first attempt is producing:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

I hooked it up to Safari's development console to find out.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to debug it, and for your answer. I thought this would only happen when doing `return foo();`, but I was obviously wrong. Using a simple loop solves it. Cheers!